# Random forest with nonnegative dependent variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, nonparametric, dependent-variable

I have a modeling framework with an outcome that must necessarily be positive. In the training data, the outcome ranges from close to zero to much higher (approximately 0.05 to 100). Is there a way to fit a random forest model for positive outcomes? Prediction accuracy is important in this problem, and I want to model the data with more flexible, nonparametric methods like random forests.

Comment: A Random Forest can not predict outside of the range of your target variable.  This is why trees are typically looked down upon when there is a significant trend for example in time series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random forest does this by default. Random forest predictions are the average of the terminal node values. The average of nonnegative values is also nonnegative.